# Preventing VMWare from sending certain key combinations to the guest

Tags: vmware

For the life of my I can't find any information on the web that explains how to prevent VMWare workstation/player from sending certain key combinations to the guest, keeping them host-only.

For instance, I'm running a full screen Debian guest inside a Windows 10 host, and need the ctrl+win+left/right combinations to always run on the host so that I can switch between desktops, and I can't even find out if that's a thing that *can't* be done, let alone how to do it if it *can*.

Comment: If you type `Ctrl-Alt` to defocus from the VM, the host's shortcuts will be honoured. Or hovering over the taskbar will have the same effect.

Comment: While true, that's also incredibly inconvenient if you constantly need to switch between the two desktops.

Comment: I've learned to live with it.

Comment: I prefer to first learn whether or not specific key intercepts are possible or not (even if that means manual vmdx hacking).

Comment: I need to do the same sort of thing with some of the remote desktop software I use, which colours my reactions. But good luck in finding your solution.

Comment: Indeed. RDP at least has the option to keep windows-key hotkeys always local, even if you can't specify the list of key combinations to keep local vs. send to the remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer some were hoping to find, but the solution for me was to make the switch from VMWare to just using Hyper-V VMs instead, opening VMs full screened on their own virtual desktop. That way, ctrl+win+left/right works seemlessly enough for me.